# Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a generic way of getting the name of Constructors. My goal is to create a Convention over configuration framework for KnockoutJS

My idea is to iterate over all objects in the window and when I find the contructor i'm looking for then I can use the index to get the name of the contructor

The code sofar

```
(function() {
    constructors = {};
    window.findConstructorName = function(instance) {
        var constructor = instance.constructor;
        var name = constructors[constructor];
        if(name !== undefined) {
            return name;
        }

        var traversed = [];
        var nestedFind = function(root) {       
            if(typeof root == "function" || traversed[root]) {
                return       
            }

            traversed[root] = true;
            for(var index in root) {               
                if(root[index] == constructor) {
                    return index;
                }


                var found = nestedFind(root[index]);  
                if(found !== undefined) {
                    return found;
                }
            }
        }

        name = nestedFind(window);
        constructors[constructor] = name;
        return name;
    }
})();

var MyApp = {};
MyApp.Foo = function() {
};

var instance = new MyApp.Foo();
console.log(findConstructorName(instance));
```

The problem is that I get a `Permission denied to access property 'toString'` Exception, and i cant even try catch so see which object is causing the problem

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4ZwaV/

**Final version in this fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/2Uvd5/8/

**Check here for the embryo of my Convention over configuration plugin**
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

Comment: Why can't you try/catch?

Comment: I can't see any exception from the fiddle

Comment: @Jan Which browser? I've only tested it in FF, you get teh error there

Comment: @Anders Chrome. Will try in FF

Comment: I could catch the exception quite easily.

Comment: Update: I could catch it twice but not the third access.

Comment: Any reason to iterate over all characters of a string?

Comment: It seems the uncatchable security error happens inside some `window.history`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce manually. Anything I try results in something catchable.

Comment: You should be safe if you don't touch any iframe window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Edit2:

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSFJy/9)</kbd>

This solves everything except for one thing: `var MyApp = {};` **doesn't** add it to the `window-object`. Changing that to `window.MyApp = {};` makes it completely working (even within an IFrame).

---

- Edit1:

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSFJy/1/)</kbd>

Adding to the array by setting the key name requires the key name to be a string so Javascript will automatically call. `toString()` on your suggested keyname which will fail for certain objects. Instead use .push() to add elements of any type to an array and then `.indexOf()` to check if it already exists.

Do note that the jsFiddle still breaks because of being placed in an `iframe`. Opening it [in a new tab](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hSFJy/1/show/) solves that.

---

*My previous answer* (which proved to be invalid when I tried to verify it in your jsFiddle):

You need to check if the constructor is an exact Object. If it is then calling .toString() on it will cause a security exception which I found to be kinda hard to debug. Here's a function I use to get the type of an object in a var-dumper I use.

```
function GetTypeOfObject(obj) {
    if (obj.constructor === window.Object)
        return '[object]';
    else
        return obj.constructor.toString();
}
```

Comment: The security exception comes from accessing into a different frame. It throws an exception for `window.top`. I am trying to find the exact object for which it's uncatchable.

Comment: See my edit (above the previous answer), that should answer your question. However for some different reason I still can't get the fiddle to work properly (unrelated to the toString security exception), so I'm fiddling in the jsFiddle to try and get it to work. I'll get back to you once I get a working jsFiddle.

Comment: @Anders it happens whenever you have a cross-domain frame. I'm trying to find a solution that works with frames.

Comment: k, also doing indexOf and push isnt that fast, beter to index like a hashtable

Comment: @Anders Objects are not identified by their string conversion. Pretty much all objects cast to `[Object object]`.

Comment: @Anders in short: crawling the entire property tree Just. Won't. Work.

Comment: Do you guys have any better idea on how to traverse throw the tree without recusing for ever because of cyclic references?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hSFJy/9/ This solves everything except for one thing: var MyApp = {}; doesn't add it to the window-object. Changing that to window.MyApp = {}; makes it completely working. Thanks for the fun challenge! :)

Comment: You're right that push and indexOf are slow but indexing like a hashtable simply won't work for objects (as indexes must be strings or ints). The only alternative I can think of is setting a property in seen objects and checking if that property exists later on to determine if you must skip it or not. This would probably be way too troublesome though (breaking many things).

Comment: I tried the approach with marking all traversed objects, but it does not work, it cant detect the flag member on the item Very strange http://jsfiddle.net/hSFJy/11/

Comment: I got a serious speed update by ignoring document and html on window. But now I have another problem, It cant find the correct name if I have more than one defined class :D http://jsfiddle.net/6USqu/2/

Comment: Aaha, im tired, when adding those flags it will only works once offcourse :D

Comment: Ok, so finally, we have a working version :D It's clocking in on 12-14 ms in FF which still is a bit slow if you have many types in your ViewModel design :/ http://jsfiddle.net/6USqu/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help, got a first version out of my library http://jsfiddle.net/2Uvd5/4/

Comment: So you did go the property setting way. Interesting. Looking good, glad you were able to get it working with a proper speed.

Comment: The user of the API can do ko.bindingConventions.init({roots: [MyApp]}); this makes the api skip window and start on the MyApp object in this case